# Why is there no planet called Proxima Centauri 'a'?

Tags: astronomy, planets

There is a newly discovered Proxima Centauri c, to complement the already-known 'b'....

Why no planet 'a'?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question as off-topic because it seems to be about names rather than physics.

Comment: It is a mixup : there is alpha, b,c stars and then planets are found around this and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha_Centauri . they probably did not want to use a two times in the system.

Comment: According to the IAU naming convention, the first discovered planet is named b, and the star itself is regarded as a. So there's never a planet "a".